# REMOVED_FROM_STAGE handler still lists the object as being in the display list, why?

Tags: actionscript-3, addeventlistener, removechild

Bug/feature:

1. create a sprite
2. add it to the display list
3. add a REMOVED_FROM_STAGE listener to the sprite
4. remove sprite
5. handler function INCORRECTLY still reports that is still in the display list

This is a problem I am facing as part of much more complex application, but I narrowed it down to its basics here. When the handler fires for REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, the currentTarget still appears to be on the display list. I need to be able to detect if it and other objects are in the display list within this function, but it appears all the info about the currentTarget is incorrect until after the handler completes its operation. At first I thought this was a render or frame issue, but my output shows it actually is more a problem with the what happens internally to the remove() command. Short of a kludge solution, does someone have insight as to why this happens?

```
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;

var sprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
addChild(sprite);
sprite.addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, removedFromStageHandler);
removeChild(sprite);
output();// shows it has been removed. No parent, no stage

function removedFromStageHandler(event:Event):void{
        output();// Still in displaylist? Has parent and stage
}

function output():void{
    trace("object = " + sprite);
    trace("  parent = " + sprite.parent);
    trace("  stage = " + sprite.stage);
}
```

Note: This odd behavior does not exist for ADDED_TO_STAGE, as the object reports its properties correct within the handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the adobe docs :

removedFromStage Event
Dispatched when a display object is about to be removed from the display list, more info [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#event%3aremovedFromStage)

So it is intended behaviour, the event is dispatched just before the item is removed from the stage, when the dispatch is complete the element is removed. This allows you to do stuff like running actions before the item is removed or even prevent the removal depending on some conditions.

Comment: ahh, "about to be removed". Thank you for that. I can see the benefit to having it fire in this order actually, as you may even want to know what the parent is right before it is about to be removed, instead of just having a null value to work with. So for my application, I will have to keep track of a removed:boolean on my own. I was hoping for way to have the event fire afterwards, such as useCapture or something, and didn't want to resort to an enterframe. It looks like it will still be kludgy for my application, but as least I know I have no other option for this situation.